# Frankie gives Maggie a "boxer name". Why do we not know the meaning before the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, million-dollar-baby

I want to understand why Frankie didn't give the meaning of "Mo Cuishle" before the end of the movie.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Thanks for the question I hadn't actually thought about it till you asked.

Answer (score 5):

Frankie was estranged from his daughter and Maggie was the closest thing to a replacement. If he had told her directly it probably would have been unwelcome to Maggie. It would have been a point of pain for Frankie and she had a family of her own. So it allowed him to say to Maggie what she meant to him in a nonthreatening way.

At the end of the movie she had become estranged from her family and he is trying to communicate to her what a loss to him it would be if she died.

At that point he basically had nothing to lose by saying what it meant.